# Is there a way to total the number of items displayed in a recyclyerView

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I would like to total the number of items displayed in the `RecyclerView`. Currently I am trying to achieve this via a `TextView`.

Here is the code in my Adapter class

```
@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    final int count = options.getSnapshots() != null
            ? options.getSnapshots().size()
            : 0;

    return count;
}
```

Here is how I am trying to achieve this in my actual class with the `recyclerview`:

```
attendanceNumbers = findViewById(R.id.attendanceNums);
    attendanceNumbers.setText(adapter.getItemCount()+ " students have attended this session");
```

Here is my full adapter class

```
public class AttendanceAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Attendance, AttendanceAdapter.AttendanceHolder>{

private AttendanceAdapter.OnItemClickListener listener;
private FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Attendance> options;


public AttendanceAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Attendance> options) {
    super(options);
    this.options = options;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    final int count = options.getSnapshots() != null
            ? options.getSnapshots().size()
            : 0;

    return count;
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AttendanceHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Attendance model) {
    holder.textViewStudent.setText(model.getUserEmail());
    holder.textViewTime.setText(model.getSignInTime());
    holder.textViewSession.setText(model.getSessionID());
    holder.textViewUserUID.setText(model.getUserUID());

}

@NonNull
@Override
public AttendanceHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.attendance_item, parent, false);
    return new AttendanceAdapter.AttendanceHolder(v);
    }

public void deleteItem(int position){
    getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference().delete();
}

public int countItems(){
    return getItemCount();
}

class AttendanceHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textViewStudent;
    TextView textViewTime;
    TextView textViewSession;
    TextView textViewUserUID;

    public AttendanceHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        textViewStudent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_student_name);
        textViewTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_course);
        textViewSession = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_student_ID);
        textViewUserUID = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_user_UID);


        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && listener != null){
                    listener.onItemClick(getSnapshots().get(position),position);
                }

            }
        });
    }
    }

public interface  OnItemClickListener{
    void onItemClick(Attendance documentSnapshot, int position);
}

public void setSetOnItemClickListener(AttendanceAdapter.OnItemClickListener listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

Here is the logcat error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.dissertation.studentscanner.AttendanceAdapter.getItemCount()' on a null object reference
```

Here is where I am creating the adapter in my class: not my adapterClass

```
private void setUpRecyclerView() {
    final Query query = attendanceRef.whereEqualTo("sessionID", "5I0PLcpgmwdcjKLYLgkU").orderBy("userEmail", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Attendance> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Attendance>()
            .setQuery(query, Attendance.class).build();


    adapter = new AttendanceAdapter(options);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    attendanceNumbers = findViewById(R.id.attendanceNums);
    attendanceNumbers.setText((adapter.getItemCount())+ " students have attended this session");
```

Comment: Currently this crashes the application

Comment: Add the logcat please which causes the crash. Also, where are you using `setText` code?

Comment: It is not very clear on logcat what is causing this. I am using setText inside the onCreate method

Comment: You can find the errors when app crashes by a red color in the logcat. Otherwise, we won't be able to help you without knowing what causes or what is the helpful point for that. You need to paste it here.

Comment: Here is the logcat errors highlighted in red:   E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded

Comment: there is a lot more than this also but none pointing as it normally does. It does not say caused by anywhere in the logcat

Comment: please post the full adapter code @Sean Gallagher

Comment: full adapter code updated @AL Tegani

Comment: attach the log errors

Comment: Logcat error attatched @AL Tegani

Comment: are you invoking `attendanceNumbers.setText(adapter.getItemCount()...` before creating the adapter?

Comment: @Lino I use it within my onCreate Method at the start of the class, this is before I set up the recyclerView. Could this be the issue?

Comment: just follow the answer posted, and see if it works

Comment: you event don't need to call **getItemCount** method, simply can get the count from options that you supposed to pass in adapter.

Comment: and how would I achieve this @Krishna Sharma

Comment: @SeanGallagher share that code where you exactly creating the adapter instance by calling **new AttendanceAdapter(<options>)**

Comment: @Krishna Sharma see edited code please

Comment: @SeanGallagher look at the answer might help

Answer (score 1):

The `NullPointerException` is caused by the fact that you're trying to invoke

```
attendanceNumbers.setText(adapter.getItemCount()+ " students have attended this session");
```

before creating the `adapter` variable.
Moving the above statement after the adapter creation will solve the issue.

Also, make sure that

```
attendanceNumbers = findViewById(R.id.attendanceNums);
```

is invoked before setting the `attendanceNumbers` text.

Comment: I am currently getting this error message :   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 1):

Requirement looks like you want to observe the count for

1) add student

2) delete student etc.

To do that create a callback like below

```
public interface CountObserver {
  void onStudentsCount(int count);
}
```

Change in Adapter class, to pass the callback

```
CountObserver countObserver;
public AttendanceAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Attendance> options,CountObserver listener) {
    super(options);
    this.options = options;
    this.countObserver = listener;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    final int count = options.getSnapshots() != null
            ? options.getSnapshots().size()
            : 0;
    if(countObserver!=null){
       countObserver.onStudentsCount(count);
    }
    return count;
}
```

**Final step**

```
CountObserver countObserver = new CountObserver(){
  public void onStudentsCount(int count){
      attendanceNumbers.setText(count+ " students have attended this session");
  }
}
adapter = new AttendanceAdapter(options,countObserver);
```

For the NPE just make sure you are calling `setUpRecyclerView` method after `setContentView` and in your activity xml layout have defined **textView** which id is `attendanceNums` for example `android:id="@+id/attendanceNums"`

Comment: where am I placing the first piece of code and the last piece sorry? Just a little confused here

Comment: move all code in your Adapter class except **Final step**, final step code should be placed inside setUpRecyclerView. Also share the onCreate/activity code where you setting you layout xml so that we can resolve NPE.

Comment: when I arrange like this my items from the recyclerView have disappeared and the TextView is still saying TextView and not set as it is supposed to be

Comment: It's hard to guess what are you doing in the code, better to share the activity class too. Can modify for the fix and share.

Comment: This saved my day. Thank you so much Krishna Sharma!